# Oracle SQL Query to get Latest Data from multiple columns in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, max

I have table MY_TABLE like this, which stores changed data(update tracking) from many tables. So whenever other table has some update, I am storing new data in MY_TABLE using `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER` on base tables.

```
ID  RECORD_DESC EMP_ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   GENDER  SALARY
1   EMP         5       ABC         XYZ                 
2   EMP         5                               M       
3   EMP         5                   XYZ-NEW     F
4   SAL         5                                       1000
5   EMP         5                               M       
6   SAL         5       ABC-NEW                         750
```

Now I want to query MY_TABLE to get employee data with latest changes from all columns and result should be like this row:

```
EMP_ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   GENDER  SALARY
5       ABC-NEW     XYZ-NEW     M       750
```

What I did up to now is, getting MAX(ID) for each column and from that ID I am querying table again to get the column value for that ID.

But problem is this query will experience quite a load on db because I have 25 columns like this and table will get larger with time.

So, can some one suggest me better way to write the query below:

```
SELECT (SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = T2.FIRST_NAME_PK) AS FIRST_NAME
     , (SELECT LAST_NAME  FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = T2.LAST_NAME_PK ) AS LAST_NAME
     , (SELECT GENDER     FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = T2.GENDER_PK    ) AS GENDER
     , (SELECT SALARY     FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = T2.SALARY_PK    ) AS SALARY
  FROM (SELECT (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE EMP_ID = T1.EMP_ID AND FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL) FIRST_NAME_PK     -- ID = 6
             , (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE EMP_ID = T1.EMP_ID AND LAST_NAME  IS NOT NULL) LAST_NAME_PK      -- ID = 3
             , (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE EMP_ID = T1.EMP_ID AND GENDER     IS NOT NULL) GENDER_PK         -- ID = 5
             , (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE EMP_ID = T1.EMP_ID AND SALARY     IS NOT NULL) SALARY_PK         -- ID = 6
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID
                  FROM MY_TABLE
               ) T1
       ) T2;
```

Comment: Post the create, insert statements for sample data and show your desired output.

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this. Don't you have an employee table containing the current values? Then you would just read this table instead, which would be a lot faster than collecting the data from a log table of course.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I just want to get whatever Update is done on the table, So if initially all fields were entered while creating the employee record. and then Only fist name is changed, then I want first name only not other column values. I want to get latest data only which are changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID, 
, LAST_VALUE(FIRST_NAME) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
, LAST_VALUE(LAST_NAME) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
, LAST_VALUE(GENDER) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
, LAST_VALUE(SALARY) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `KEEP` clause as follows:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(FIRST_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN FIRST_NAME IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ID END DESC NULLS LAST) AS FIRST_NAME,
       MAX(LAST_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN LAST_NAME IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ID END DESC NULLS LAST) AS LAST_NAME,
       MAX(GENDER) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN GENDER IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ID END DESC NULLS LAST) AS GENDER,
       MAX(SALARY) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN SALARY IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ID END DESC NULLS LAST) AS SALARY
  FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? See comments within code.

```
SQL> with my_table (id, record_Desc, emp_id, first_name, last_name, gender, salary) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 1, 'emp', 5, 'abc', 'xyz', null , null from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'emp', 5, null, null, 'm', null from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'emp', 5, null, 'xyz-new', 'f', null from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'emp', 5, null, null, null, 1000 from dual union all
  7     select 5, 'emp', 5, null, null, 'm', null from dual union all
  8     select 6, 'emp', 5, 'abc-new', null, null, 750 from dual
  9    ),
 10  temp as
 11    -- find last values
 12    (select a.id,
 13      a.record_desc,
 14      a.emp_id,
 15      last_value(a.first_name ignore nulls) over (partition by a.record_desc, a.emp_id order by a.id) first_name,
 16      last_value(a.last_name  ignore nulls) over (partition by a.record_desc, a.emp_id order by a.id) last_name,
 17      last_value(a.gender     ignore nulls) over (partition by a.record_desc, a.emp_id order by a.id) gender,
 18      last_value(a.salary     ignore nulls) over (partition by a.record_desc, a.emp_id order by a.id) salary
 19     from my_table a
 20    )
 21  -- extract only the last row per RECORD_DESC and EMP_ID
 22  select *
 23  from temp c
 24  where c.id = (select max(b.id) From my_table b
 25                where b.record_desc = c.record_Desc
 26                  and b.emp_id = c.emp_id
 27               );

        ID REC     EMP_ID FIRST_N LAST_NA G     SALARY
---------- --- ---------- ------- ------- - ----------
         6 emp          5 abc-new xyz-new m        750

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your employee table has the current data. You only want to show the data that has been altered, though.

What I'd do is show the employees data in case the column has an update in the log table. We don't have to find the latest update, because no matter how often the column was updated, the employee table contains the last value. This is a very simple operation in spite of having to read the whole log table.

```
select
  e.emp_id,
  case when log.some_first_name is not null then e.first_name end as first_name,
  case when log.some_last_name  is not null then e.last_name  end as last_name,
  case when log.some_gender     is not null then e.gender     end as gender,
  case when log.some_salary     is not null then e.salary     end as salary
from employees e
join
(
  select
    emp_id,
    min(first_name) as some_first_name,
    min(last_name)  as some_last_name,
    min(gender)     as some_gender,
    min(salary)     as some_salary
  from my_table
  group by emp_id
) log on log.emp_id = e.emp_id
order by e.emp_id;
```

An alternative to running this query again and again would be a last_updates table with one row per employee and a trigger that fills it on every insert into the existing log table. If you need this often, that's the route I'd choose.